# Bit shift through an array

Tags: c, arrays

Say we have 8 bytes saved in an array like:

```
char array[8];
```

All of them are set to zero:

```
for (i = 0; i < 7; i++){
array[i] = 0x00;
}
```

How can shift a `1` from the first LSBit until the last MSBit like

```
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x04
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x08
0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x10
```

.....................................

to

```
0x08 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x10 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x20 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x40 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

Here is what I've tried but the result isn't what I'm looking for:

```
    uint8_t buffer[8];

int index = 0 ;
for ( index = 0; index < 8; index++){
        buffer[index] = 0x00;
    } 
*buffer= 0x01;
for( index = 0 ; index < 64; index++){
        *buffer = *buffer<< 1 ;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Here is an example of what I get:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
char buffer[2]={0x01, 0x00};
int i ;
for( i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++){

  printf("0x %2X    %x \n",buffer[0], buffer[1]);
  *buffer <<= 1;
  }

}
```

And the output is:

```
0x  1    0
0x  2    0
0x  4    0
0x  8    0
0x 10    0
0x 20    0
0x 40    0
0x FFFFFF80    0
0x  0    0
0x  0    0
0x  0    0
0x  0    0
```

I really don't understand the 0xFFFFFF80!

Comment: You forgot to carry the one

Comment: @ harold thanks for your answer, but what do you mean

Comment: The question would make sense if you asked how to shift it left by **an arbitrary number of bits**. If you just want to shift it all the way from the LSB to the MSB, then you can simply set `buffer[0] = 0x00` and `buffer[7] = 0x80`.

Comment: @Engine: Please don't update your question so often. It is confusing and also might render some answers obsolete. Looking at the answers I see that it is not quite clear what you want: Do you want to implement a bit-shift across the byte buffer or do you simply want to loop through all 64 configurations that have a single bit set?

Comment: @ M Oehm I want to shift 1 through 8 byte saved  in array, meaning I need 63 shifts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What byte that is "LS byte" and which one that is "MS byte" is perhaps not obvious. An array of 8 characters is *always* allocated in memory like this:

```
LS address               MS address
Byte 0, ...              Byte 7
```

This is true for all CPUs. So the `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01` in your question doesn't make any sense: you have misunderstood how arrays are allocated in memory. What you have shown in your examples is how to take bit 0 in the ms byte and left shift it to bit 7 in the ls byte. Which probably doesn't make any sense.

*However*, if you would attempt to print this array as a 64 bit integer, the value `array[0]=1` would give you `0000000000000001` on a little endian machine, but `0100000000000000` on a big endian machine. But nothing in your question states that you want to print the array as a 64 bit value, so it is not clear what you are actually asking.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


typedef union
{
  uint8_t array[8];
  uint64_t u64;
} my_type;

int main()
{
  my_type t = {0};
  t.array[0] = 0x01;
  // how the array is actually allocated:
  for(int i=0; i<8; i++) // 0100000000000000 on all machines
  {
    printf("%.2X", t.array[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  // how the array turns out when printed as a 64 bit int:
  printf("%.16llX\n", t.u64); // 0000000000000001 little endian

  // perhaps what you intended to do, on a little endian machine
  t.u64 <<= 63;
  printf("%.16llX\n", t.u64); // 8000000000000000 little endian

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: your answer look pretty good I can't test now but when I do and it work  I will accept it

Comment: thanks again for your help, and your answer is a way better than what I've done !

Answer (score 2):

As per harold's comment, just carry the 1. So, to shift one place:

```
uint8_t carry = 0;
for( index = 7 ; index >= 0; index--){
    uint8_t nextCarry = buffer[index] >> 7;
    buffer[index] = (buffer[index] << 1) | carry;
    carry = nextCarry;
}
```

EDIT: also, it strikes me that your CPU **almost certainly has a native 64-bit type**. In which case just use a `uint64_t` directly rather than an array of bytes and perform `variable <<= 1;`.

Comment: Yes, but `buffer[index]` should be something like `buffer[index / 8]`, no? Or maybe even another special variable to complement the carry.

Comment: Oh, yes, rather index should go up only to 8. A bad copy and paste, I'm afraid. Corrected.

Comment: Thanks. But I think there's still an error: You should increment the `index` only if there is a carry. (The loop index seems to be independent from the `buffer` index.)

Comment: On the contrary, whether there's a carry or not should have no effect on `index`. The bit from the top of byte n goes into the bottom of byte n+1, whether it was a 1 or a 0.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Try out your code and print the array. You'll see that you operate only on ' buffer[index]', whereas the carry should come from `buffer[index - 1]`. Also, when making the change, you changed the number of loop cycles from 64 to 8.

Comment: @Tommy: Okay, what your code does is to perform a single shift across the byte buffer. Sorry for my misconception. (I thought that the whole loop would pass the single one byte from LSB to MSB.)

Comment: @Tommy I've tried your answer but the result aren't correct

Comment: @Engine I was looping the wrong way around. The least significant byte is on the right, not the left. A mental endianness fault. Fixed.

Comment: @Tommy thanks for the hint with the carry variable , I've answered the question ! thanks a lof

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but the following code does at least what was posed in the question:

```
uint8_t temp = buffer[0];

printf("Initial Buffer :\n");
for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
    printf("0x%X ", buffer[7-i]);

// Left Shift until highest bit that is 1 is found
while(!(temp & 0x80))
    temp = temp<<1;

// Re-assignments
buffer[7] = temp;
buffer[0] = 0;
printf("\nFinal Buffer :\n");
for(int i = 0 ; i < 8 ; i++)
    printf("0x%X ", buffer[7-i]);
```

In true sense, this is not "shifting entirely through the buffer", but if you could provide more details on what you wish to accomplish, this code could be modified accordingly.

Comment: Yes. These are some of the results:
[0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x01] // Initial ->
[0x80 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00] // Final

[0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x7F] // Initial ->
[0xFE 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00] // Final

[0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x05] // Initial ->
[0xA0 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00] // Final

[0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0xFF] // Initial ->
[0xFF 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00] // Final

Comment: Sorry about my comment. All the formatting gets automatically removed.

Comment: I interpreted the question differently to mean more like "how can I perform a bit shift across an array as though it were a single integral", but I can see the logic in this code: shift the least significant byte until it has the most significant bit set, then swap it up to the most significant byte. That would shift from LSB to MSB more quickly than touching every bit in between if you know the interesting bits are initially confined to the least significant byte.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to treat your char array as a single 64 bit object, why not use an actual 64 bit object?

```
union
{
    char array[8];
    uint64_t all;
} data;

int index = 0;
data.all = 0;
data.array[0] = 0x01;

for(index = 0; index < 64; index++)
{
    data.all = data.all << 1;
}
```

Note that this assumes that you are working on a little endian machine.

Comment: That makes an endianness assumption you might like to mention, especially as the original question is using a big-endian array but most CPUs are little endian nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

So I've done it , maybe it's not the best way but it works, and if someone needs I'll be glade to share it :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main (){
uint8_t buffer[8];
char* pChar = buffer;
uint8_t  carry  =0x01;
int i = 0;
short lock [8];

// Array  initialization

for ( i =0  ; i <8; i++){
   buffer[i] =0x00;
   lock[i] = 0x00;
}

pChar =buffer;



for( i = 0 ; i < 64 ; i++){
  *pChar = carry;
  printf(" 0x%2x   0x%2x   0x%2x  0x%2x  0x%2x 0x%2x 0x%2x  0x%2x \n",buffer[0], buffer[1],buffer[2],buffer[3], buffer[4], buffer[5], buffer[6], buffer[7]);
   carry<<=1;
  if( i>=7 && lock[0]==0){
    *pChar = 0;
    pChar++;
    carry=0x01;
    lock[0]=1;
   }else if ( i>=15 && lock[1]==0) {
     *pChar = 0;
      pChar++;
      carry=0x01;
      lock[1]=1;
    }else if( i>= 23 && lock[2]==0){
     *pChar =0;
      pChar++;
      carry=0x01;
      lock[2] =1;
      }
      else if( i>= 31 && lock[3]==0){
        *pChar =0;
         pChar++;
         carry=0x01;
         lock[3] =1;
      }
       else if( i>=39 && lock[4]==0){
           *pChar =0;
           pChar++;
           carry=0x01;
           lock[4] =1;
       }
         else if( i>= 47 && lock[5]==0){
          *pChar =0;
          pChar++;
          carry=0x01;
          lock[5] =1;
         }
        else if( i>= 55 && lock[6]==0){
          *pChar =0;
          pChar++;
          carry=0x01;
          lock[6] =1;
        }



}
```

thanks for your help !